# UISearchDisplayController, how to register a prototype build in storyboard editor

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a simple `UITableViewController` subclass, that shows different cell prototypes.
I've also added a `UISearchDisplayController` to manage the search, unfortunately if I try to search something it crashes.
This is due to the fact that I'm trying to dequeue a cell that was not registered in the `UITableView` owned by the search display, and I understand that.
Is there any way to easy register one without (solutions already proposed on different SO answers):

- creating another cell xib programmatically equal to the one already loaded
- registering a new class or a nib
- hacking things that could be easily broken in future releases
- dequeuing cell for the first table view and creating new for the search table view

I've tried to find a property in `UITableView` that list already registerd nib or class to pass the info to the search table view but it doesn't exist

Comment: UISearchDisplayController load another UItableView when you search. What's your code?

Comment: @www thanks. I know, my code is fine everything is working, the question is merely informative

Comment: Bottom line, the answer is no, the suitable solutions to the problem are all iterated in your question, furthermore, of those answers, really the only good answers are the first two.  If you're worried about duplicating the cell layout, why not just use the xib or class registered for the search controller in the base controller as well?  I think that's what I'd do under the circumstances.

Comment: Thanks @David , to solve the problem I 've created another xib by copying and paste from the storyboard, and registering it to the search table view. I think that this is a silly problem left from Apple, I was hoping that since they are pushing Storyboard so much there would be a way to do from the editor.. I was wrong